# how to register notification for other application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing iPhone application where i need to capture other application's notification in my application. **Example** I have **hello world** and **test** application in my iPhone. I want to capture **hello world** notification in **test** application. How to do this? and
I have register the application using local notification i.e

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self   
 selector:@selector(handleAppFinishLaunching)
 name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
 object :nil];
```

This registers my application itself. what other values i can give for addObserver?

Comment: You can't capture notifications sent in other applications. The apps are sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can register a custom URL scheme in the receiver application like `notification://` and then pass some data using `[UIApplication openURL:]` in the sender app. The receiver should handle this in application delegate with `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

You can find some info on registering custom URL schemes at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way of interprocess communications in iOS